# how to change a column type in array struct by pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-schema

how to change a column type in array struct by pyspark, for example, I would like to change `userid` from int to long

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- numbers: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
        |-- m1: long (nullable = true)
        |-- m2: long (nullable = true)
        |-- m3: struct (nullable = true)
           |-- userid: integer (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Do you want the results in structured format and then cast it to `long` ?

Comment: @DKNY yeah, structured format won't be changed and only `userid` changed

Comment: @Frank See my edits. Have used a reproducible example with a schema exactly like yours. Happy to help further if needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would have been useful if you provide a reproducible df as well.

Following you comments below see the following code.

```
  sch= StructType([StructField('id', StringType(),False),StructField('numbers', ArrayType(
  StructType([StructField('m1',LongType(),True),
              StructField('m2',LongType(),True),
             StructField('m3',StructType([StructField('userid',IntegerType(),True)]),True)])),True)])



df=spark.createDataFrame([
  ('21',[(1234567, 9876543,(1,))]),
  ('34',[(63467892345, 19523789,(2,))])
], schema=sch)
  
  

df.printSchema()

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = false)
 |-- numbers: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- m1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- m2: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- m3: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- userid: integer (nullable = true)
```

Solution

```
df1 = df.selectExpr(
  "id",
  
  "CAST(numbers AS array<struct<m1:long,m2:long, m3:struct<userid:double>>>) numbers"
)

df1.printSchema()

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = false)
 |-- numbers: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- m1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- m2: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- m3: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- userid: double (nullable = true)
```

Comment: schema is quite complicated, so reproducible schema is not good to me

Comment: Ok, edited to have the exact schema like you had. Happy to assist further if needed

Comment: @wwnde This looks fab mate. I was trying out by putting everything in a structured fashion and then cast it. Great piece of learning for me today!

Comment: Ahh sorry forgot to do that. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out another solution, possible since Spark version 3.1.0, making use of higher-order functions, in this case the [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html) function.

I find it safer and more robust since one can reference columns by name and safely change their names or data types, whereas with the previous method we're subject to the risk of inconsistency when input data schema changes over time, since that method references columns by position (i.e. it will call the first column that it gets `m1` regardless of its content or name)

The new proposed solution is implemented with `df2` below:

```
sch= StructType([StructField('id', StringType(),False),StructField('numbers', ArrayType(
  StructType([StructField('m1',LongType(),True),
              StructField('m2',LongType(),True),
              StructField('m3',StructType([StructField('userid',IntegerType(),True)]),True)])),True)])



df=spark.createDataFrame([
    ('21',[(1234567, 9876543,(1,))]),
    ('34',[(63467892345, 19523789,(2,))])
], schema=sch)
  
df1 = df.selectExpr(
    "id",  
    "CAST(numbers AS array<struct<m1:long,m2:long, m3:struct<userid:double>>>) numbers"
)

df2 = df.selectExpr(
    "id", 
    """
    transform(numbers, s -> struct(                    
        cast(s.m1 as long) as m1,
        cast(s.m2 as long) as m2,
        struct(cast(s.m3.userid as double) as userid) as m3
    )) as numbers
    """)

df.printSchema()
df1.printSchema()
df2.printSchema()
```

With the following schema results in each case:

```
df:
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = false)
 |-- numbers: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- m1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- m2: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- m3: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- userid: integer (nullable = true)

df1:
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = false)
 |-- numbers: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- m1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- m2: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- m3: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- userid: double (nullable = true)

df2:
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = false)
 |-- numbers: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- m1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- m2: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- m3: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- userid: double (nullable = true)
```

Note however that when creating the structs in this way, there is no way yet in PySpark to explicitly make the struct field nullable (`nullable = true`) as it will infer from data, which should be fine in most practical cases.